# javascript modal for quiz

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

i am making a quiz for a project, how do i make javascript check whether answer is correct for a specific question?

eg. the quiz is "where is this food from?" and there are 4 different images which javascript chooses from to display and make the user guess. the first picture is from turkey, then greece, india, then mongolia. if the turkey picture comes up, and the user types turkey, how do i make it so that javascript checks whether the user input is correct?

code right now

````
    var img1 = ("https://cdn.madeinturkeytours.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/vegan-cig-kofte.jpg")
    var img1answer = ("turkey")
    var img2 = ("https://deih43ym53wif.cloudfront.net/large_spanakopita-greek-food_dd3bda740c.jpeg")
    var img1answer = ("greece")
    var img3 = ("https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/53099699.cms?width=1200&height=900")
    var img1answer = ("india")
    var img4 = ("https://www.travelbuddies.info/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/tsuivan.jpg")
    var img1answer = ("mongolia")
    var imagearray = new Array(img1, img2, img3, img4);
    var randomimagesrc = imagearray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagearray.length)];
    document.getElementById("img1").src = randomimagesrc;

    var answers

    var div = document.getElementById('imagebtn');
    div.style.display = 'none';

    document.getElementById("guess").style.visibility="visible";

    document.getElementById("hint").style.visibility="visible";

    document.getElementById("imagebtn").innerHTML = "Next Round!";
  }


  function guess() {
    var txt;
    var guessinput = prompt("Enter Your Guess Here! ")
    **THIS IS THE PART WHICH I NEED HELP WITH**
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

There is a few issues with your snippet, such as you keep creating the variable img1answer. I suggest you look to create an array of objects because it will make it easier to link the answer with the image.

I created a basic example of this below.

```js
// You want to create an array of objects, it will be much easier to relate the answer to the image this way.
const quizzData = [
  { image: "https://cdn.madeinturkeytours.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/vegan-cig-kofte.jpg", answer: 'turkey' },
  { image: "https://deih43ym53wif.cloudfront.net/large_spanakopita-greek-food_dd3bda740c.jpeg", answer: "greece" },
  { image: "https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/53099699.cms?width=1200&height=900", answer: "india" },
  { image: "https://www.travelbuddies.info/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/tsuivan.jpg", answer: "mongolia" },
];

// Get the random image here.
const randomImage = quizzData[Math.floor(Math.random() * quizzData.length)];
alert(`The answer is ${randomImage.answer}`)

const guessinput = prompt("Enter Your Guess Here! ")

// Compare the guess with the answer
if (guessinput === randomImage.answer) {
  alert("correct");
} else {
  alert("wrong");
}
```

Comment: hi I tried doing this everything works but the displaying of image does not.

Comment: hi, I did not add in any html, or Javascript to interact with the html, was just to demonstrate a cleaner way to link images with the answers and show you how to compare your answer with the actual answer, as well as fix some issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the correct answer when picking the random image.

```
 var imagearray = new Array(
[img1, img1answer],
  [img2, img2answer],
  [img3, img3answer],
  [img4, img4answer]
);

var randomimagesrc = imagearray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagearray.length)];
document.getElementById("img1").src = randomimagesrc[0];

var answer = randomimagesrc[1];
```

And then you can check the prompt value with the answer value.

```
function guess() {
var txt;
var guessinput = prompt("Enter Your Guess Here! ")

if(guessinput === answer) { 
    alert("Correct Answer!"); return 
}
alert("Wrong answer!") 
}
```

You can check the live example https://jsfiddle.net/athishayd/zpk206xo/